# Why does the "or" operator in the if statement not work?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, or-operator

Why does the if statement in the for loop not work properly? "0,1" is still being returned as True although it is smaller than 2. Code is a bit sloppy, sorry.

```
def isprim(n):
    for i in range(2,n-1):
        if n % i == 0 or n < 2:
            return False
    return True

for i in range(50):
    if isprim(i):
        print(i)
```

Output is:

0
1
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47

Comment: 0, 1, 2 won't enter the loop because of the `range(2, n-1)`. And so, it will always return `True` for those numbers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not demonstrate any actual misbehavior on the part of the language or runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `n = 0`, `n = 1` or `n = 2`, the function does not execute the loop, because the loop's `range` starts from 2, thus the function skips the loop and returns `True`.

Comment: But I'm checking if n < 2 not i < 2
n is the integer I'm checking if it's a prime number or not.

Comment: you checked it in the loop, and the loop runs from 2 to n-1. so if n smaller than 2, the loop range is empty and the loop won't run

Comment: Got it! Thank you. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in isprim(n) is never entered since 2 is larger than both 0 and 1 for range(2, n-1). Therefore, return True is always executed for those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Game it out:

- Loop from 0 to 49
- Iteration 0 -> isprim(0)
- Loop from 2 to -1 -> range(2, -1) is an empty list
- return True
- Iteration 1 -> isprim(1)
- Loop from 2 to 0 -> range(2, 0) is an empty list
- return True
- Iteration 2 -> isprim(2)
- From here on, n is always greater than or equal to 2.

So your issue is the `for i in range(2, n-1)`. In the REPL:

```
>>> len(range(2, -1))
0
>>> len(range(2, 0))
0
>>> len(range(2, 1))
0
>>> len(range(2, 2))
0
>>> len(range(2, 3))
1
```

For those first few numbers that are prime, you're better off putting in explicit tests:

```
def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    if n not in [1,2]:
        for i in range(2, n-1):
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for

```
def isprim(n):
   for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0 or n < 2:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    # Special case for 2
    if n==2:
        return True
```